# vba- Userform with three comboboxes

Tags: excel, vba

I need some guidance how to create a selection for a excel userform that when the user selects CB1 which may be in A2, that it will also select the next cell B2 for the populated field and also select the next cell in C2 for the next populated field. I am not sure if my first selection should be a CB and the next fields maybe a list box or text field.
current code is:

```
Private Sub Userform_Initialize()
ComboBox_Combox5.List=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A650").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: `CB1` is a cell reference or short for combo-box1?  Do you mean the value in combo-box1 may appear in cell `A2`?  Will the position of the item in the combo-box relate to the row on the sheet that the value is in, i.e. the first item in the combo-box is on row 1?

Comment: Correct. The value in Combobox1 may appear in A2 and it is related to the row in the sheet. It is a long list starting from A2, B2, and so on.

Comment: You could change the `ColumnCount` property for the combo-box to 3, adjust the column widths to suite and update the code you posted to look at `A1:C650`.  The combo-box will then show the values from the three columns.

Comment: Or did you mean select the value from the combo-box and it will select the cells on the sheet?

Comment: To select the cells on the sheet use `Private Sub ComboBox_Combox5_Change(): ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Me.ComboBox_Combox5.ListIndex + 1, 1).Resize(, 3).Select: End Sub`

Comment: Column A has the part number so when the part number is entered, i also need it to populate the next two fields. Each part number in column A has the part number, Column B has the description, and Column C has the location. My apoligies for not making clear.

Answer (score 0):

Add two text boxes next to your combo-box.
I've left them with the default names of `TextBox1` and `TextBox2`.

[image]

Code behind the form is:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Userform_Initialize()
    ComboBox_Combox5.List = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A650").Value
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox_Combox5_Change()

    'Reference to selected value in column A.
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Me.ComboBox_Combox5.ListIndex + 1, 1)
    
    Me.TextBox1 = rng.Offset(, 1)
    Me.TextBox2 = rng.Offset(, 2)
    
End Sub
```

Always have [Option Explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/option-explicit-statement) at the top of your module.

Comment: I attempted to test the code and am receiving a runtime error 424 object not found.

Comment: The error is within the Option Explicit

Private Sub Userform_Initialize()
    ComboBox_Combox5.List = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A650").Value
End Sub. If i remove this from the form it opens , however does not provide me with the list.

Comment: I just used your code for that bit.  Replace `ComboBox_Combox5` with the name of your combo box `Sheet1` for the name of the sheet with your data.

Comment: I did just that, however the debug continues to highlight the line on the Private Sub ComboBox5 initialize (). I know it is close to working but continue to hit this error.

Comment: The sub name should be left as `Private Sub Userform_Initialize()` , just make sure the name of the control within the procedure is correct.

Comment: I tried again, now I am able to run the form , however as soon as I type the part number into the CombBox5 it populates the run time error '424' on line:   Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Me.ComboBox_Combox5.ListIndex +  1, 1)